# I would like to improve a search replace function in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, search, replace

```
var target   = $(".target-text"),
    relation = ['spun gold', 'gold', 'apple'],
    len      = relation;

for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    var e = relation[i],
        re = new RegExp(e,"ig");

    if (e.length > 0) {
        target.html( target.html().replace(re, "<span class='hit'>$&</span>") );
    }

};
```

The searched characters are surrounded with a tag.

At this time, There is a problem.
The problem is that a result changes in the turn to search.

like a `['spun gold', 'gold', 'apple']` is ok,
but like a `['gold', 'spun gold', 'apple']` is ng.

If `gold => <span class='hit'>gold</span>` is performed first,
`spun gold => <span class='hit'>spun gold</span>` will go wrong.
(Since `gold` has changed to `<span class='hit'>gold</span>` by the 1st time.)

Is there better way?

---

EDIT:

As conditions, search is not only English.

Comment: Would it be ok if you just reorder relation-array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see the problem: one replacement is messing up a previous one because they share a common substring.

Perform a single replacement, by combining the terms in `relation` into one big "or" in the regexp:

```
var target   = $('.target-text'),
    relation = ['spun gold', 'gold', 'apple'],
    re = new RegExp(relation.join('|'), 'ig');

target.html(function (_, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(re, "<span class='hit'>$&</span>");
});
```

**N.B.** you may need to quote the array elements before `.join('|')`ing them to prevent special characters from breaking the regexp. (Example: `relation = ['foo', 'bar?']`). Here's how: [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex/6969486#6969486)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried.
The result of `['tress', 'enchantress']` is `<span class="hit">enchantress</span>`.
I want to it become like `<span class="hit">enchan<span class="hit">tress</span></span>` as my image. Is it possible?

Comment: If a pre-code is executed after this your code, it will become as my image. Thank you. (but is there wastefulness?)